# Python script to strip new lines from .txt files contained in a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of .txt files contained in a directory. Each file may have multiple lines. What could be the Python script to strip off all newlines from all the files contained in that directory? The resulting files should have exactly one line containing all the texts.

```
import os
os.chdir("/home/Pavyel/Desktop/Python Programs")

for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if i.endswith(".txt") :
    f = open(i)
    contents = f.read()
    new_contents = contents.replace('\n', '')
    print i
    continue
else:
    continue
```

Comment: There could be many scripts... have you tried to write one yet?

Comment: import os
os.chdir("/home/iitp/Desktop/Python Programs")

for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if i.endswith(".txt") :
        f = open(i)
        contents = f.read()
        new_contents = contents.replace('\n', '')
        print i
        continue
    else:
        continue

Answer (score 1):

Use [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#glob.glob) to find the files of interest, i.e. those that end with `.txt`. `glob()` returns a list of matching filenames and also leaves the path intact, so you don't need to change directories.

Process the files in place with [`fileinput.input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input):

```
import fileinput
from glob import glob

pattern = '/home/Pavyel/Desktop/Python Programs/*.txt'
files = glob(pattern)
if files:
    with fileinput.input(files, inplace=True) as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line.rstrip('\n'), end='')
```

If you are using Python 2 it might be worth passing `mode='U'` to `fileinput.input()` to ensure that universal newline processing is enabled, as is the default for Python 3. With that enabled you can be sure that `\n` will match newlines regardless of the platform on which your code runs.

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
import sys
import fileinput

dir = "." #Directory to scan for files

file_list = os.listdir(dir)

for file in file_list:
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        with fileinput.FileInput(file, inplace=True, backup=".bak") as f:
            for line in f:
                sys.stdout.write(line.replace("\n", ""))
```

This will also create a backup of all files it edited, just in case.
If you don't want the backup remove `, backup=".bak"` from the 7th.

Comment: problem with this line : print(line.replace("\n", ""), end="")

Comment: @Pavyel **You** are running an incompatible version of Python. Most likely Python 2 because it doesn't support the new print function. The script works just fine on my computer. Anyways I've changed the code so it works with more Python versions.